# how to get a specific file(sound file) when the file name is called by a variable in using Pyglet

Tags: python, python-playsound

When using module pyglet, giving the name of mp3 explicitly like sound="10.mp3", it works.
When using module playsound and giving filenames as variable,
playsound(str(play_num) + '.mp3'), it does work.

```
playsound(str(play_num)+'.mp3')
```

But when applying variable name of file to pyglet just like below, sound = "str(play_num)+'.mp3'", it does not work.

```
sound = "str(play_num)+'.mp3'"
```

it shows FileNotFoundError.
How can I solve this problem???
In addition how to get the files from other directory and some other folder?
When getting a sound file in other directory/folder using variable ?

```
player = pyglet.media.Player()
sound = "str(play_num)+'.mp3'"
src = pyglet.media.load(sound)
player.queue(src)
```

Comment: why `sound` is inside quotations?!

Comment: because when using explicit file name, there are quotations like 
sound = ".\\S-WORD-E-SE-B-V-2\\10.mp3" it did work.

Comment: `sound = str(play_num)+'.mp3'`

Comment: Yes, but this case is when the sound files are in the current working directory. if when the sound files are in the other folder, how can i write on one sentence ? I solved this with two split sentences like [os.chdir("location of sound files")/ playsound(str(play_num)+'.mp3'] . It does work, But is it possible to combine these two in one sentence?

Comment: You have too many quotes... You have `"str(play_num)+'.mp3'"` when it should just be `str(play_num)+'.mp3'`

Answer (score 0):

Use F-String:

```
sound = f"{play_num}.mp3"
```